# MVC Web app can't find view in Area with subfolders

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a folder structure as follows:

[image]

In my `Startup.cs` I have:

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
 {
     endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
        "Admin",
        "Admin",
        "admin/{controller=Dashboard}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

     endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
 });
```

In my ```FormsController` I have:

```
[IsRole(RoleEnum.Admin)]
[Area("Admin")]
[Route("admin/forms")]
public class FormController
{

    [HttpGet("skips")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditSkip()
    {
        return PartialView("Skips/_Edit.cshtml");
    }
}
```

For some reason, the view can't be found as I get this error message:

The view 'Skips/_Edit.cshtml' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Skips/_Edit.cshtml

I've tried using:

```
return View("~/Areas/Admin/Forms/Skips/_Edit.cshtml");
```

But still no luck, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong I've followed everything on Google and other stackoverflow answers but I've got to be missing something

Comment: Are you running locally or publishing to the production environment? It's okay to use absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

you missed a view folder.  try this url

```
return View("~/Areas/Admin/Views/Forms/Skips/_Edit.cshtml");
```

Comment: I thought the same, but this doesn't work either :( You'd think because my area is defined in the routing that it would search these folders any way without having to specify the full path

Comment: @KTOV I am sorry but the full path is always working